# How to push an object in an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Iam trying to push in array an object, but I get always error.

```
fCElements = [],
obj = {};

obj.fun = myFunction;
obj.id = 2;

fCElements.push ({

   obj,
   myid:2,
   name:'klaus'     

})
```

how I can push into array functions like "myFunction"?

Thanks

Comment: what error did your get

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid object initializer
 

fCElements.push ({

          ReferenceError: init is not defined

Comment: You have a syntax error in your object literal, so the code won't be executed. Most likely you have something else called `init` in the same code block that won't be created, and the error comes from some other code expecting it to be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Object literal, you can only give key-value pairs. Your `obj` doesn't have any value.

Instead, you can do like this

```
var fCElements = [];
fCElements.push({
    obj: {
        fun: myFunction,
        id: 2
    },
    myid: 2,
    name: 'klaus'
});
```

Now, you are creating a new object, `obj`, on the fly, while pushing to the array. Now, your `fCElements` look like this

```
[ { obj: { fun: [Function], id: 2 }, myid: 2, name: 'klaus' } ]
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to give your obj property a name (or a value).

```
var obj = {};

obj.fun = myFunction;
obj.id = 2;

fCElements.push ({

   obj:obj,
   myid:2,
   name:'klaus'     

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The object you are pushing to the array seems off. It will try to push this object:

```
{
    {fun: myfunction, id: 2},
    myid: 2,
    name: 'klaus'
}
```

Which is an invalid object since the first value has no key. You should do it like this instead:

```
fCElements.push ({
   myObj:obj,
   myid:2,
   name:'klaus'     
});
```